# SQL - update field with a value, if corresponding values are all the same

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have an interesting task at hand that I'm trying to figure out how to do.

Let's say I have the following data in a table:

```
  Num1      Acct      Amt         Type1       Type2        AmtX     AmtY    AcctBadInd
  X12       111       90           X          1            NULL     NULL    NULL
  X12       222       -90          X          1            NULL     NULL    NULL
  X12       333       90           X          1            NULL     NULL    NULL

  Y33       111       75           Y          1            NULL     NULL    NULL
  Y33       444       -75          Y          1            NULL     NULL    NULL

  Z44       111       55           Y          1            NULL     NULL    NULL
  Z44       111       55           Y          0            NULL     NULL    NULL
  Z44       444       -65          Y          1            NULL     NULL    NULL
```

Below are a couple examples. Only caveat is that a given Num1 can have any number of records but always >= 2. So it could be 2,3,4,5 and the same logic would apply in all cases.

1. Verify that `ABS(AMT)` for all `Type2=1` records is the same. If all 3 records have the same AMT, then `SET AMTX=ABS(AMT)` for that Num1. Alternatively, if `Type1 was Y for X12` - then we would instead update `AmtY = ABS(AMT)`
2. `Num1 = Y33` - In this case we again want to verify that `ABS(AMT)` is the same where `Type2=1`. If they are equal, then because `Type1=Y`, we would set `AmtY =75`
3. `Num1=Z44` - in this case again verify that ABS(AMT) is the same for `Type2=1`. If they are not equal, then dont update AmtY, but rather set `AcctBadInd = 1`

End Result

```
Num1      Acct      Amt         Type1       Type2        AmtX     AmtY    AcctBadInd
  X12       111       90           X          1            90     NULL    NULL
  X12       222       -90          X          1            90     NULL    NULL
  X12       333       90           X          1            90     NULL    NULL

  Y33       111       75           Y          1            NULL     75    NULL
  Y33       444       -75          Y          1            NULL     75    NULL

  Z44       111       55           Y          1            NULL     NULL    1
  Z44       444       -65          Y          1            NULL     NULL    1
  Z44       111       55           Y          0            NULL     NULL    NULL
```

I'm struggling with this, and I'm not expecting an answer but at least a hint or any help so I can get on my way. More so, if this is doable in a way that I imagine without writing god knows how much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly here is how you can do it:

```
with cte as (
select * , type2, max(abs(Amt)) minAmt, min(abs(Amt)) maxAmt, count(*) cnt 
from table 
group by Num1 , type2
);

update t1
set   AmtX = case when cnt> 1 and Type2=1 and t1.type1 = 'X' and minAmt = maxAmt then minAmt end
    , AmtY = case when cnt> 1 and Type2=1 and t1.type1 = 'Y' and minAmt = maxAmt then minAmt end
    , AcctBadInd = case when cnt> 1 and Type2=1 and minAmt <> maxAmt then 1 end
from table t1 
join cte on t1.Num1 = cte.Num1
and t1.type2 = cte.type2
```

Comment: Thanks - good thought. I was thinking about taking SUM(ABS(AMT)) and then dividing it by Count

Answer (score 1):

Using window functions

```
with t as (
    select *,
    AmtXnew = case when min(ABS(AMT)) over(partition by Num1, Type2) = max(ABS(AMT)) over(partition by Num1, Type2) 
                     and Type2 = 1 and Type1 ='X' then ABS(AMT) 
                else NULL end,
    AmtYnew = case when min(ABS(AMT)) over(partition by Num1, Type2) = max(ABS(AMT)) over(partition by Num1, Type2) 
                     and Type2 = 1 and Type1 ='Y' then ABS(AMT) 
                else NULL end,
    AcctBadIndnew = case when min(ABS(AMT)) over(partition by Num1, Type2) <> max(ABS(AMT)) over(partition by Num1, Type2) 
                     and Type2 = 1 then 1 else NULL end
    from tbl
)
update t set AmtX = AmtXnew,AmtY = AmtYnew, AcctBadInd = AcctBadIndnew;
```